# JSON array-like object, add item

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have a JSON file which contains:

```
[{"id":1,"first_name":"Judith","email":"jshaw0@wikipedia.org"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Sarah","email":"sross1@infoseek.co.jp"},
{"id":3,"first_name":"Dorothy","email":"dgreene2@posterous.com"},
{"id":4,"first_name":"Christine","email":"cnichols3@techcrunch.com"},
{"id":5,"first_name":"Theresa","email":"trogers4@xrea.com"},
{"id":6,"first_name":"Rebecca","email":"rpeterson5@mlb.com"},
{"id":7,"first_name":"Chris","email":"cbailey6@yellowpages.com"},
{"id":8,"first_name":"Howard","email":"hbailey7@miibeian.gov.cn"},
{"id":9,"first_name":"Sara","email":"ssimpson8@techcrunch.com"},
{"id":10,"first_name":"Lois","email":"lmartinez9@dion.ne.jp"},
{"id":11,"first_name":"Jeffrey","email":"jhalla@intel.com"},
{"id":12,"first_name":"Teresa","email":"tcampbellb@usnews.com"},
{"id":13,"first_name":"Susan","email":"skingc@wired.com"},
{"id":14,"first_name":"Richard","email":"rpattersond@omniture.com"},
{"id":15,"first_name":"Ronald","email":"rgreenee@wordpress.org"}]
```

I want to add one more element to it but I can't figure it out how.
I have the following node code:

```
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
var util = require('util');

var file = 'data.json';
var jsonObj = {};
jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
    jsonObj = obj;

    new_obj = {"id":16,"first_name":"Florin","email":"popflorin1705@yahoo.com"};
    //jsonObj.push(new_obj)
    console.log(typeof jsonObj);

    /*jsonfile.writeFile(file, jsonObj, function (err) {
      console.error(err)
    })*/
});
```

I've tried to use push method, but obviously is not working because it is an object not an array, even if it looks as an array. Which would be a good way to add another row at the end of the object (or array - I'm confused)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String to Array of JSON Objects (Node.js)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673702/convert-string-to-array-of-json-objects-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable

```
 var new_obj = {"id":16,"first_name":"Florin","email":"popflorin1705@yahoo.com"};
```

And then use `push()` as you have done already. Give it a try. It will work only if `obj` is json object as you mentioned in question.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're forgetting to parse JSON. After reading the file, your code should be:

```
jsonObj = JSON.parse(obj);
```

instead of straight assignment.

Comment: undefined:1
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object
 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at /home/florin17/Desktop/Work/Express/server/app.js:10:20
    at /home/florin17/Desktop/Work/Express/server/node_modules/jsonfile/index.js:20:5
    at fs.js:268:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)